# Fix display value changing on child of flexbox. Inline-block being overridden

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I've recently starting using flexbox and this is the first problem I've run into. I want my `.wrp` class below to remain `display: inline-block;` but one line seems to disable this value. That line is: `flex-direction: column`. When I remove that line my .`wrp` class starts behaving like an `inline-block` element again but then of course it loses it's `flex-direction` value. Is there a simple solution that doesn't require restructuring my HTML too much to keep the `flex-direction` behavior of flexbox but also keep the inline-block behavior on `.wrp`?

```css
.contr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* this line seems to be breakig my display on .wrp */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.wrp {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="contr">
  <div class="wrp">
    <p>I want this paragraph to stretch to fit it's content. Not full width.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not `flex-direction` that disables the child's `display: inline-block`. It's `display: flex` that does it. When you establish a flex container, the children are automatically *blockified*. Any specified `display` value on flex items is ignored.

Comment: That's the rule in the spec. But obviously, as evident in the answer below, `display: inline-table` is an exception.

Comment: @Michael_B It seems it is both `flex-direction` and `display:flex`. Your solution changes the width and/or behavior of the whole flex container which is why I chose the former solution, which seems to isolate the problem and fix it without any side effects.

Comment: The accepted answer appears to be a hack. Again, declared `display` values on flex items should be ignored by the browser. I wouldn't rely on that solution, as browsers may eventually conform to the spec.

Comment: Does `.wrp` necessarily have to be content-width, or really just the `p` (as stated in your code comment)? https://jsfiddle.net/kk33j8r6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an `inline-block` element within a flex. It looks like you may be looking for `display: inline-table`:

```css
.contr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* this line seems to be breakig my display on .wrp */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.wrp {
  display: inline-table;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="contr">
  <div class="wrp">
    <p>I want this paragraph to stretch to fit it's content. Not full width.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Any insight on how `display: inline-table` works in this situation? Thanks.